# Rails devise session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

In devise, say if i wanted to force a session to start, not checking if email or password are right, just starting a session for a particular user, how would i that

(so maybe, the user sends in a parameter through the url with his username, i pass that to a function in my sessions controller, which starts a session for that user)

I've looked around and i can't find a solution for this problem.

```
def create
   name = params[:name]
   user = User.where('name == :name', {:name => name})
   user = user[0]
   function to force session start
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sign_in function

```
sign_in(:user, user)
```

Comment: I spent hours tinkering in the devise controller, and the solution was really that simple?